# How to update SRID in PostGIS database

Tags: postgis-2.0

I am facing a problem when I am trying to execute few queries in PostGIS. It returns the following messages.

```
    ERROR:  GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys

********** Error **********

ERROR: GetProj4StringSPI: Cannot find SRID (4326) in spatial_ref_sys
SQL state: XX000
```

What I am missing and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Postgis is telling you that it cannot find the entry 4326 in the spatial_ref_sys table.

Probably you missed a couple of steps in your installation procedure.